# Ubuntu 12.04 I can't download anything... at all

Tags: 12.04, installation, apt, synaptic, aptitude

I recently upgraded from Maveric(10.10) to 12.04 (by wiping out Maveric from my system completely) I was using a pen drive, so it messed up my grub. I finally managed to reinstall the grub on the machine and now it boots fine.

Now,I can't download anything from the Software-center or manually. I followed some advice on the forums that included purging the software centre, but once i tried to reinstall, it refused. I checked my software sources they all seem ok. I'm set to main server. I can't install anything.

Answer (score 2):

If there is an issue with the software centre, try reinstalling it.

Press CTRL+ALT+T simultaneously to enter terminal.

To uninstall Software Center:

```
sudo apt-get remove software-center

sudo apt-get autoremove software-center
```

To re-install Software Center:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install software-center
```

If the software centre is working fine, check if the internet connection is working properly.

Press CTRL+ALT+T simultaneously to enter terminal.

Type rfkill list

It should display the lan ,blurtooth and wifi options.If any of it is blocked, enter

rfkill unblock wifi  (to correct wifi options).

Comment: tried it, but nothing seems to work:

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal by going to Applications->Accessories->Terminal

Enter the command:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

then

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If it gives you any error messages, it will tell you what command to run to fix the error.

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Hi Nefro I tried running the sudo apt-get update command and it returns an error:
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: Check your added repositories. Maybe some of them are broken. 
Look at _Systemsettings > Software Sources_ (or Software & Updates, it's called something like that) and then look at "Other Software"